# The number of vs The numbers of

Tags: grammatical-number, numbers

I always get confused whether I should use singular or plural for "number".

Below are example sentences.

1: There was a similar pattern in the number of car theft and robbery throughout the period given.

2: There was a similar pattern in the number**s** of car theft and robbery throughout the period given.

Because the number in this sentence indicates two things which are car theft and robbery, I thought I should use plural.

I would like to know which one is correct to use in this case.

Thank you for in advance.

Comment: Neither example is correct.  "... the number of car **thefts** and **robberies** ..."

Comment: They're plural ***car thefts*** and ***robberies*** in your context. Usually, ***number*** would be singular, but you might validly use plural ***numbers*** if you're thinking of the car thefts and the robberies as completely different things which are counted separately, ***and*** you think that's important enough to try to get across (but not so important that you're willing to construct a much longer text, to make absolutely certain your audience will understand that specific point).

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my questions with the details!